# mac keyboard (slim w/numpad) - can't select multiple Alt/Win key behaviors?

Tags: 11.10, keyboard-layout

As I'm switching between my Macbook Air and my new ubuntu stationary frequently, I'd like to use mac keyboard and key combos for both. I'd like to **select two of the options below**, not just one

"**Left Alt is swapped with Left Win**" solved a lot of problems, allowing me to switch between running apps.

"**Meta is mapped to Win Keys**" made my Rubymine work smoothly, as Meta/Cmd key is used for a lot of shortkeys.

Please advice, thanks!

[image: keyboard layout options mac keyboard]

Comment: I'm not sure if this is possible. When you press `Left Win`, how will your computer know if you mean `Left Alt` or `Meta`? Even it it were possible to map two keystrokes to one key, this seems like it would cause all kinds of conflicts. Could you map a different key to meta instead, e.g. `Right Command`? (It's mapped to `Shift`-`Left Win` on my aluminium Apple keyboard.)

Comment: I don't even know how it know's the diff now. With `Left Alt swapped with Left Win` it shows both `Meta L` and `Alt L` on my Alt/option key (mac slim). I understand now it will be very hard to get a similar experience on mac and linux, make my everyday switch tougher.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Are you saying that you *can* get both mapped to `Left Alt` in Linux somehow? Or is this just in OS X?

Comment: Also, for RubyMine specifically, apparently there's "advanced keyboard" layout preferences, where you can map `Meta` to `Left Win`. (I use NetBeans for Ruby, but I've been thinking about switching to RubyMine.)

Comment: Thanks @Sparhawk. I'm actually using "Meta is mapped to win keys now", and disabled (in Compiz) the opening of dash that used to happen when pressing this key. I switch tabs using alt+tab, not cmd+tab, copy paste is through ctrl+c, not cmd+c and some more annoying differences that I can live with (ctrl+shift+c in terminal for copy is really frustrating). I haven't used NetBeans in years, but I still highly recommend RubyMine. Can't find any "advanced keyboard" in RubyMine, I think your confusing this with Ubuntu's. I found that my changes are similiar to this: http://grosser.it/tag/ubuntu/

Comment: I'm trying out RubyMine now. And I agree with your comment regarding keybinding. Despite what I've read on the web (e.g. http://grosser.it/2009/10/01/switching-to-rubymine-from-netbeans-on-ubuntu/ ), I can't find how to map `Meta` to `Left Win`. However, you do know that you can change all keymaps, right?

Comment: change all keymaps: not really. I know about xev to identify key, which I've used to change the norwegian keyboard mapping directly (changing some existing wrong mappings, not creating new). I'm afraid changing too much will lead to unexpected behavior and that the time investment will never pay off.

Comment: Sorry, I was being ambiguous. I didn't mean to change keymaps at a system level, but within RubyMine. (Also, I'm definitely a RubyMine convert now I've used it for a week or so! It's much better than NetBeans.)